# Error 438 while running Outlook macro from PowerPoint

Tags: vba, outlook, powerpoint

I am trying to run a public macro defined in Outlook from PowerPoint.

I get error 438 on the line where the Outlook macro is called.

My VBA code in PowerPoint;

```vb
Sub RunOutlookMacro()
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookNamespace As Object
  
    Set OutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.application")
    Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    OutlookApp.Run "ThisOutlookSession.TestOutlook"       'TestOutlook is the macro in Outlook

    Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

The macro being called in Outlook;

```vb
Public Function TestOutlook()
    msgbox "You have reached Microsoft Outlook"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook's Application Object does not support the Run method.

```vb
Sub RunOutlookMacro()
Dim OutlookApp As Object
Dim OutlookNamespace As Object

Set OutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.application")
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

' Err 438 Object doesn't support this property or method
'OutlookApp.Run "ThisOutlookSession.TestOutlook" 'TestOutlook is the macro in Outlook

' Move all the code from "TestOutlook" into PowerPoint
MsgBox "You have reached Microsoft Outlook"

Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```